# videojs-http-streaming browser memory heap always grows

Tags: video, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, video.js, live-streaming

I met an issue when player is playing, the "browser memory heap" snapshot always grows.

[image]
On screenshot: for the left-side browser window I'm using "my-custom-live.m3u8" life stream, for the right-side window I'm using standard 'bip-bop.m3u8' video stream.

This issue especially affects low memory android video consoles like X96 Mini. Browser just crashes in 2 hours. Samsung TV (900$ price) also crashes.

Any thoughts on this?

> PS: If I use deprecated videojs-contrib-hls
>   https://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/ it does not happen. The
>   heap size remains the same.

Environment:

- Chrome: Version 74.0.3729.157 (Official Build) (64-bit) test
- link https://videojs.github.io/http-streaming/